# Light sensors doesn't get values during a loop

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

My code is this.

```
public void foo()
    {
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
             int i=0;
             while(i<10000) //sleep, or something else
                     i++;
             //print the currentLux's value
    }
```

-

```
 public void foo()
    {
            new lt().start()
            int i=0;
            while(i<10000) //sleep, or something else
                    i++;
            //print the currentLux's value
    }
class lt extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
}
```

And the sensor event is this:

```
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
    {
        currentLux+=event.values[0];
    }   
}
```

This is my problem. I need to create the light sensor and then wait a little (something like 5 seconds) and then check the sum of the values. The problem is that if i use a sleep, a loop or something else, the sensor doesn't get any value. What can i do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're pausing the main thread, and that way the `onSensorChanged` function never called. You should register your listener in `onResume`, and use [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to execute the display code after the specified delay.